# "Одно и то()же" — когда слитно, а когда раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу запомнить различие между "тоже" и "то же". Особенно это касается выражения "одно и то же". Я никак не могу понять, когда именно в этом обороте "тоже" пишется раздельно, а когда слитно.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Одно и то же - всегда раздельно. Например, каждый день повторяется одно и то же (т.е. то же самое).

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сказал так: если фразу можно дополнить словосочетанием "... что и ...", тогда "то же" пишется раздельно, иначе слитно.

Answer (score 1):

В этом сочетании, несомненно, раздельно. Но не стоит забывать, что существует и слитное написание: "он пришёл, я тоже". Если "ЖЕ" нельзя убрать или перенести на другое место в предложении, то оно пишется слитно.